# Is this a bad audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Going through the close-vote queue, I came across and failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6640579).

However, I don't think my decision to leave the question open was wrong. The question was closed as unclear, but I think it's clear enough to be left open. It asks to select a particular array from the JSON by comparing the first element in each sub array, which is (assumingly) guaranteed to be unique, to a given number.

Am I wrong or is this a bad audit?

Comment: It doesn't show the code that has been tried,nor how or where this should be used in iOS (if that is possible at all). It can be xcode (or whatever it is called) or maybe javascript inside safari on an iOS device...

Comment: @rene I didn't notice the tags, I assumed it was looking for a JS solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you understand what the asker wants, you should've edited it to make that clear to everyone else.** After reading the question, I'm not at all sure this is answerable in its current state:

- As noted in comments, there's no language specified; that's a problem for anyone wishing to provide code in an answer, and if you click through to the question you'll see that in fact [it *did* cause problems for an answerer who guessed wrong and had to delete his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717684/parsing-json-based-on-tag-containing-particular-string-in-ios/27717767#27717767). You *could* edit the question to clarify this based on the information in the comments on that now-deleted answer if you wished... Of course, so could have the asker.
- His requirement is, for a given ID, "to get data of that total array". There are two arrays in his sample JSON: the one containing the nodes, and the one containing the faqs for each node. You could assume he wants the latter, I suppose - but I actually suspect he wants the full node and simply doesn't know what JSON objects are called. Maybe he meant to write "array element"? Or maybe he wants the result of some calculation made upon the node; I'm really just guessing now - if he'd provided an *example* of the output he wanted, this would've been trivial to answer.

In short, it was closed because we need additional details. Which is what the close reason states, and what - even after closure - the author didn't provide. Again, if *you* think you can make a reasonable guess as to what he's after here, feel free to edit it - that would've passed the audit, and for non-audit reviews that would've provided some significant benefit to others in exchange for keeping the question open.

As the instructions for close reviewers state...

[image: Edit if this question could be improved so that it does not need to be closed.]

Answer (score 5):

Not to put too fine a point on it, but you're wrong in this case.

What this question lacks:

- **Clarity.**  The tags mention that they're using iOS, but they don't specify what language, framework, or approach they're using to get this JSON.
- **Good faith attempt.**  To the point of no language being specified, there's simply no code to go off of to say that they had made some effort to parse JSON.  Nor do they describe what errors they encountered while attempting to parse the JSON.

The question doesn't also appear to be editable to be made more clear, as it reads more like, "here's the JSON, show me the code to parse please!"  Definitely not something we want to be on the site, and definitely an audit that requires action.